# CakePHP HABTM table won't insert data with existing key

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a problem with my `HABTM` table.

This is the model structure:
Team <- EmployeesTeam -> EmployeesAdditionalData

```
'EmployeesSecondary' => array(
    'className' => 'EmployeesAdditionalData',
    'joinTable' => 'employees_teams',
    'foreign_key' => 'team_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'bv'
)
```

(bv is some sort of an Employee ID)

Everytime I try to save data in the HABTM Table with `$this->Team->save()` as well as `$this->Team->EmployeesTeam->save()` it saves the first entry perfectly, but then assumes, that the team_id would be the primary_key (even when I set the bv as PK or erase the whole primary index).

So, when I try to assign another Employee to the Team it updates the first entry and doesn't insert a new one.

```
INSERT INTO `employees_database`.`employees_teams` (`bv`, `team_id`) VALUES (3781, 3);

UPDATE `employees_database`.`employees_teams` SET `bv` = 3345, `team_id` = 3 WHERE `employees_database`.`employees_teams`.`team_id` = '3'
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are the different indexes which are on the table employees_teams?  It sounds like team_id is either a primary or unique key

Comment: First I had two primary keys: bv and team_id like you do in m:n tables. While debugging I set only bv as only primary key and also deleted the primary index. The result was always the same. They're also both not set unique.

Comment: I'd remove the primary keys from the table, and then have a combination of the bv and team_id as a unique key.  If you really need them to be individually indexed, then set those fields to be a normal index rather than a primary or unique key

Comment: Doesn't work either.

I just checked the primary key of the virtual model with
`pr($this->Team->EmployeesTeam->primaryKey);`
It really is the team_id. I never set a primary_key. Why did CakePHP set a primary key?